# Возвратить массив из функции

Tags: php

Данная функция должна возвратить массив с папками БЕЗ использования глобальных переменных. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

```
function dirFinder ($folder)
{
    $all_in_folder = scandir($folder);
    foreach ($all_in_folder as $value) {
        if ($value == '.' || $value == '..') continue;
        $path_to_object = "$folder\\$value";
        if (is_dir($path_to_object)) {
            $arr[] = "$folder\\$value";
            dirFinder($path_to_object);
        }
    }
}
```

Папки должны записываться в данный массив:

```
$arr[] = "$folder\\$value";
```

В результате должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
Array
(
    [0] => W:\mysite.loc\Папка 1
    [1] => W:\mysite.loc\Папка 1\Папка 2
    [2] => W:\mysite.loc\Папка 1\Папка 2\Папка 3
    [3] => W:\mysite.loc\Папка 1\Папка 2\Папка 3\Папка 4
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправлен код функции:

```
function dirFinder ($folder)
{
    $arr = [];
    $all_in_folder = scandir($folder);
    foreach ($all_in_folder as $value) {
        if ($value == '.' || $value == '..') continue;
        $path_to_object = "$folder\\$value";
        if (is_dir($path_to_object)) {
            array_push($arr, "$folder\\$value");
            dirFinder($path_to_object);
        } 
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Если используете php скрипт в среде Linux, вместо `"$folder\\$value"` используйте другой разделитель `"$folder/$value"`

Второй вариант:

```
function dirFinder ($folder, $arr = null)
{
    if ($arr === null) {
        $arr = [];
    }
    $all_in_folder = scandir($folder);
    foreach ($all_in_folder as $value) {
        if ($value == '.' || $value == '..') continue;
        $path_to_object = "$folder".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."$value";
        if (is_dir($path_to_object)) {
            array_push($arr, "$folder".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."$value");
            $arr = dirFinder($path_to_object, $arr);
        } 
    }
    return $arr;
}

$arr = dirFinder("C:\\mysite.loc");

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97640/discussion-on-answer-by-n-s-nikolaev----).